# My apps not list in My apps when i has installed

Tags: android, tracking, google-play, currency

My apps ( Money Lover - https://market.android.com/details?id=com.bookmark.money) has a bug, when i installed apps on market, market not list it on my apps . Can i help me !!!

Comment: so you're saying the app IS on the system and runnable but when you click "My Apps" in market it isn't listed?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the following code in your manifest under the Activity class that you want to be launched when your app is started?

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
```